# How to set window over another?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am writing a custom tooltip window (let's call it A). It has to be displayed over another window (let's call it B) and:

- Do not steal the focus from the B
- Do not lose its position in z-order to B while user continues input into B
- A must recieve WM_NCHITTEST messages (i use them to track mouse position over inactive window)
- When another window is brought over B, it must be brought over A as well; situation where B is covered and not visible, but A is displayed should be averted

I have tried to implement this by using the SetWindowPos function, calling its wrapper (defined in A) from B like this:

```
    public void SetLocation(Point location, IntPtr UnderHandle)
    {
        SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, location.X, location.Y, Width, Height,
                             SetWindowPosFlags.DoNotActivate);

    }
```

(SetWindowPosFlags from pinvoke.net)

The result satisfies almost all my needs except the lst one.

What have i also tried:

- HWND_TOP: does not brings window A over active window B; to be more precise: immediately after the call, it does bring window A to foreground, but then B goes to foreground instead; in practice, while B is moved by the title bar and mouse button is pressed, window A is drawn over it - but goes under the moment mouse button is unpressed
- calling SetWindowPos with UnderHandle as first parameter and Handle as second, in attempt to "bring window B under window A" yields the same result

How should SetWindowPos be usd correctly to achieve desired result - or, alternatively, how can window B's position in zorder be monitored to force window A into position next to it (from being a foreground window)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly `HWND_TOPMOST` is your problem and you certainly must not do that. You could use `HWND_TOP`, but then the challenge is how to keep window A on top of window B. The way to do that is to make A be [owned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows) by B.

> **Owned Windows**
>
> An overlapped or pop-up window can be owned by another
>   overlapped or pop-up window. Being owned places several constraints on
>   a window.
>
> - An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.
> - The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is
>     destroyed.
> - An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.
>
> Only
>   an overlapped or pop-up window can be an owner window; a child window
>   cannot be an owner window. An application creates an owned window by
>   specifying the owner's window handle as the *hwndParent* parameter of
>   `CreateWindowEx` when it creates a window with the `WS_OVERLAPPED` or
>   `WS_POPUP` style. The *hwndParent* parameter must identify an overlapped
>   or pop-up window. If *hwndParent* identifies a child window, the system
>   assigns ownership to the top-level parent window of the child window.
>   After creating an owned window, an application cannot transfer
>   ownership of the window to another window.

In fact, as you can see from the first bullet point above, once the ownership is correctly setup, there's no need for `HWND_TOP`.

Comment: Thank you! As per your advice, i set A.Owner=B nad got what i wanted.